# MySQL SELECT query returning false when prepared

Tags: php, mysql

My file should get all users with this id (It's only one since id is unique in this table) and prepare a statement to execute later. When I execute it I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on
>   boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gamanware.ga\Admin\update.php:7 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Gamanware.ga\Admin\update.php on line 7.

And I can't see anything wrong with it. The id is alright (I echo it out to be sure), Im not using reserved words and have made sure that it won't matter anyway, but I still get this error. I have been on several forums and many questions have not worked for me. I hope some of you can! 
 My code:

```html
<?php

require '../includes/login_system.dbh.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=:id';
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([':id' => $id ]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please edit your post to include the relevant contents of `login_system.dbh.php`?  It is probably helpful assuming this is PDO to enable its exceptions. By default PDO errors silently.

Comment: After connecting, you would add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` then at the time `prepare()` is called, you'll see the issue reported as a catchable exception.

Comment: It could be mysqli_ where named parameters aren't supported.

Comment: If you var_dump `$conn->error` (for `mysqli`) or the result of `$conn->errorInfo()` (for `PDO`), does that provide any hints as to why preparing the query failed?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below and see if it helps

```
require '../includes/login_system.dbh.php';
$sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id"; 
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$id = $_GET['id'];
$statement->execute();
```

You can also do an `if else` statement with your execute like so to see what it gives you.

```
require '../includes/login_system.dbh.php';
$sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id"; 
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($statement->execute()) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Comment: This is still going to result in the fatal error `Call to a member function execute() on boolean` unless the logic to test success is moved to the `prepare()` call instead of the `execute()` call.

Comment: He should really be using `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` @MichaelBerkowski